# Лучший git plugin для intellij idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Ситуация примерно такая: работаю на нескольких проектах, везде разные репозитории от gitLab до Azure repos.
С локальной тачки в любимой intellij idea бывают ситуации что просачивается автор коммита вместе с email с другого проекта. Редактировать постоянно global settings у git план не очень удобный. Есть ли на подобный вопрос удобное решение (быть по внимательнее не подходит :))

Comment: удобное решение - local settings

Answer (score 0):

А если после клонирования проекта конкретно в этом проекте переопределить имя/почту? Тогда будет работать оно, а не глобальное.

Comment: редачить конфиг git прямо внутри проекта: 
.git/config и докидывать туда строки name и email. Уже так делал, вариант хороший

Comment: Достаточно убрать `--global` из команды :)